# Link style in svg by dvisvgm output

Tags: hyperref, dvisvgm

dvisvgm converts my presentation with links indicated by a frame around it. My test file is named *Hyper_Test.tex*. I get this with following commands sequence:

1. latex Hyper_Test.tex
2. latex Hyper_Test.tex
3. dvisvgm --font-format=woff --exact --zoom=-1 -p1- Hyper_Test

But I don't want the frames around the links. Giving options to hyperref does not work. Why?

My MWE is:

```
% working, but ugly
\documentclass[dvisvgm,hypertex,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
% not working, because there are no links to click
% \documentclass[dvisvgm,hypertex,hyperref={hidelinks},aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PageDown, PageUp key event handling; navigation symbols
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[totpages]{zref}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
    \special{dvisvgm:raw
      <defs>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      <![CDATA[
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
          if(e.key=='PageDown'){
            \ifnum\thepage<\ztotpages
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax.svg');%
            \fi
          }else if(e.key=='PageUp'){
            \ifnum\thepage>1
              document.location.replace('\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage-1\relax.svg');%
            \fi%
          }
        });
      ]]>
      </script>
      </defs>
    }%
  }%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeftForeground{%
    \raisebox{-\dimexpr\height+0.5ex\relax}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
      \normalsize\color{structure!40!}%
      \ifnum\thepage>1%
        \href{\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage-1\relax.svg}{\faArrowLeft}%
      \else%  
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowLeft}%  
      \fi\hspace{0.5ex}%
      \ifnum\thepage<\ztotpages%
        \href{\jobname-\the\numexpr\thepage+1\relax.svg}{\faArrowRight}%
      \else%
        \textcolor{lightgray}{\faArrowRight}%  
      \fi%
      \hspace{0.5ex}%
    }}%
  }%  
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter

% this default might be overridden by plain title style
 \newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
 % (ERT) argument for the TOC
 \AtBeginDocument{%
   \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
   \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
   \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
 }

\usetheme{Montpellier}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vskip1.5em}{\vskip0.5em}{}{}
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[]
{
   \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Overview}
      \tableofcontents[currentsection, hideallsubsections]
   \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
   \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{Contents}
      \tableofcontents[
          sectionstyle=show/hide,
          subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide
      ]
   \end{frame}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Harald Lichtenstein}
\institute{Institute}
\date{\today}
\makebeamertitle

\part{Part 1}

\section{Intro}

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title 1}
    Info
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title 2}
    more Info
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title 3}
    more Info
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title 4}
    more Info
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title 5}
    more Info
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title 6}
    more Info
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `dvisvgm` option `--output=%f-%0p.svg` if the DVI has more than 9 pages; otherwise the forward/backward links and PgDown/PgUp do not work.

Comment: You can use dvisvgm option `--linkmark=none` to disable the rectangles around linked areas.

Comment: And perhaps, for `beamer`-class documents, `--bbox=papersize` should be preferred over `--exact`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all contributors in the comments above who in fact answered my question.
To close this issue I like to summarize the comments:

Not the options in the `\documentclass` solve the problem, but the options given to `dvisvgm`.

The command lines, which deliver the desired output are:

1. `latex Hyper_Test.tex`
2. `latex Hyper_Test.tex`
3. `dvisvgm --font-format=woff --bbox=papersize --output=%f-%0p.svg --linkmark=none --zoom=-1 -p1- Hyper_Test`

Where the option `--linkmark=none` does that there are no frames around the links anymore as described by Martin in comment above. In addition the option `--output=%f-%0p.svg` is very useful, because the numbering of more than 10 slides would otherwise lead to problems with the linkage between them as described by AlexG in comment above.